# Array.sort safari issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the array:

```
var arr = [
    {id: "d", sequence: 3},
    {id: "c", sequence: 4},
    {id: "b", sequence: 2},
    {id: "a", sequence: 1},
    {id: "e"}
];
```

and want to sort it with follow logic:

- element without `sequence` should be first
- other should be sorted by descending `sequence`.

My solution is:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (!a.sequence || !b.sequence) return 1;
  return b.sequence - a.sequence;
});
```

I've expected following order:

```
[{id: "e"}, {id: "c", sequence: 4}, {id: "d", sequence: 3}, ...]
```

but in safari receive:

```
[
  {id: "c", sequence: 4}, 
  {id: "d", sequence: 3},
  {id: "b", sequence: 2},
  {id: "a", sequence: 1},
  {id: "e"}
]
```

Why in Safari `{id: "e"}` is the last element, when in Chrome and Firefox it is first?

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Always returning `1` regardless which of the two (or both) have no `.sequence` property cannot work, it's not a [valid comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24080786/1048572). That it worked in Chrome and Firefox is more by luck.

Comment: A shorter code than Pointy's would be `function(a, b) { return (b.sequence || Infinity) - (a.sequence || Infinity); }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your sort comparator does not do what you say you want it to do. If you want the lack of a "sequence" property to mean an element should be before elements *with* such a property, your return value has to reflect that:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (("sequence" in a) && !("sequence" in b))
    return 1;
  if (("sequence" in b) && !("sequence" in a))
    return -1;
  if (!("sequence" in a) && !("sequence" in b))
    return 0;
  return b.sequence - a.sequence;
});
```

(This could probably be done with a little less code; it's explicit for clarity.) It's important that a sort comparator function always returns consistent results for every pair of elements (in either order).

Your existing code behaves differently between browsers because sort implementations vary between runtime systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#sort` like this:

1. The first part of the `return` expression checks if `sequence` exists,
2. while the second part order the `arr` in *descending* order.

See demo below:

```js
var arr=[{id:"d",sequence:3},{id:"c",sequence:4},{id:"b",sequence:2},{id:"a",sequence:1},{id:"e"}];

var result = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return +('sequence' in a) - +('sequence' in b) || b.sequence - a.sequence
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: you could omit plusses, because minus convert boolean operands to number.